# How to forward std::initializer_list<T>?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I am trying to forward a `std::initializer_list` but

```
no known conversion from 'std::initializer_list<A>' to 'std::initializer_list<B>'
```

Here is the test code

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
};

class A: public B {
};

class not_working {
    private:
    void fun(std::initializer_list<B> p) {
    }
    public:
    template<typename T>
    not_working(std::initializer_list<T> args) {
        fun(args);
    }
};

class working {
    private:
    void fun(std::initializer_list<B> p) {
    }
    public:
    working(std::initializer_list<B> args) {
        fun(args);
    }
};

int main(){    
    working{A{}, A{}};
    //not_working{A{}, A{}};
}
```

How can I forward the `std::initializer_list`
without explicit casting `not_working{(B)A{}, (B)A{}};` ?

### Why is this a problem for me ?

I have a proxy-class that forwards the constructor-parameters to a class.
Something like this:

```
 template<typename T>
 class proxy {
    T real;
    template<typename S> proxy(std::initializer_list<S> p): real(p) {}
    template<typename S...> proxy(S ... p): real(p ...) {}
};
```

Comment: Can `fun` be a function template?

Comment: In your `proxy` class' `proxy(S...)` ctor, you could use `real{ std::move(p)... }` to invoke an initializer-list ctor of `T`.

Comment: @dyp no `fun` can't be a function template. Of course it could. But I don't want to have templates in my classes.

Comment: The fundamental problem is the same as trying to pass an array of `B` to a function that only knows `A`: It cannot know the size of `B`. You could use some weird pointer arithmetic like `qsort`, for example (if you need polymorphism), or a callback etc to extract the next `A&` from this array. You could also copy the elements (slicing).

Comment: Oh, hmmm. Creating a new `initializer_list` is rather ugly, since there's no runtime mechanism to set the number of elements. One would have to use some kind of `switch`, but in C++11 recursion is required to make that `constexpr` (if your compiler support creating `initializer_list`s inside constant expressions in C++11).

Comment: Uh, yes, it's quite ugly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27758ae34145f724 Maybe it can be simplified?

Comment: @dyp post your `real{ std::move(p)... }` as solution, I will accept it. I got it working this way.

Comment: @dyp it just looks like it creates a tmp-object and then calls copy-constructor. When initializer-list constructor doesn't exists.

Comment: ? "it" referring to what? Also, I don't quite know *how* you introduced the braced-init-list in your code; in theory you can replace almost all `initializer_list` ctors with variadic ctor templates (so I don't know how you solved it).

Comment: @dyp it referring to the comment above. But it looks like it was a mistake. It works 100% correct. 
Check out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa25389a7ee8a386
anways post it as answer, I want to accept it.

Comment: can confirm; this works @KoKuToru

Answer (score 3):

You cant, and the reason is the same as why you also could not cast a `std::vector<A>` to a `std::vector<B>`. Containers of different types are *completely* unrelated.

The only way to "change" the type of a container is to construct a new container of the new type (eg, `std::vector<B>(a.begin(), a.end())` -- but beware of slicing!).

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer from comments of question to increase visibility of the solution:

Standard solution is to use std::forward. This fails forwarding initializer lists.

```
template<typename T>
     class proxy {
        T real;
        public:
            template<typename ... S> proxy(S ... p): real{std::forward<S>(args)...} {}
    };
```

Using std::move, also works with std::initializer_list (provided by @dyp) :

```
template<typename T>
 class proxy {
    T real;
    public:
        template<typename ... S> proxy(S ... p): real{std::move(p) ...} {}
};
```